# Bitbucket credentials issue in source tree and git

Tags: bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am not sure if this is the correct place for this. I used source tree to clone a bit bucket repo and was able to do it a couple of months ago. I was also able to push and pull. However, recently when I try to push and pull or even clone down another copy using the same credentials i get an invalid credentials message.

I have tried clearing out the windows credential manager, resetting my atlassian password, and trying to clone on a completely different computer with the same result.

It's weird because I can add my bitbucket account to source tree using the username and password but I cannot clone, pull, or push using those same credentials.

I do not have an errors message screenshot but could get one if the issue is not clear.

Thanks!

Update: Here is an interesting behavior happening out of sourcetree, when I try to clone a repo I get multiple login prompts. All of these fail when using the credentials.

[image]

Comment: Have you upgraded SourceTree  recently? I have seen one of my colleagues having exactly same issue. We couldn't figure out problem and he ended up using different client.

Comment: @binarymemoir Yes! This is the newest version.

Comment: I can only suggest to downgrade and try again :(

Comment: @binarymemoir would you be able to recommend an alternative? I found Git kraken.

Comment: Git Kraken is really awesome. If you are moving from SVN to Git then TortoiseGit has UI very much similar to TortoiseSVN which makes things easier.

Comment: @binarymemoir thanks! Sadly it is not free for commercial use so I will have to find a different one. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the newest version of source tree has a few issues to work out. Downgrading to an older version, 1.9 I believe, I was able to perform cloneing, pulling, and pushing without issue.

I decided to look for alternative clients but source tree would still work on an older version.

Comment: @binarymemoir so I ended up trying the version directly behind the current version so running 2.6.9 worked! It's the update 2.6.10 that has the issue.